# PowerShell: Multiple Body responses from API

Tags: powershell

I am using a GET method to pull data from StatusHub API.

This is an example response from the API

```
{
        "id": 3570,
        "title": “[SevA] Test title”,
        "incident_updates": [
            {
                "id": 9329,
                "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur.INC1085710<br/>",
                "id": 9328,
                "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud. INC1085710<br/>",
```

As you can see there are two different "body" responses under "incident_updates" which ultimately fall under the same issue title of  "title": “[SevA] Test title”.

How am I able to pull out just the latest "body" response and not all of them?

I have tried doing something like

```
$response.incident_updates.body[0]
```

however the problem with that is that it picks up the first latest body response which is perfect, however I need the first response for every single incident and not just one.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: the ID values are not the same

Answer (score 0):

First of all the Json shouldn't have duplicate values. When I look at the documentation of StatusHub for [incidents](https://api-docs.statushub.com/?version=latest#2f41b8e5-f8dc-49e4-bee4-3ca1ca2a18b2) and [incidentUpdates](https://api-docs.statushub.com/?version=latest#3bb67590-21e9-4802-827c-65aeccd5a9c7) it shows a clear separation of each incident id in a different array index.

second the json you post will truncate the properties `id` and `body` when using `ConvertFrom-JSON` because a `PSCustomObject` or `Hashtable` do not allow duplicate keys.

if you keep getting duplicate properties within a single object, I would advise on reporting this to StatusHub and describing Cleary on the exact steps taken that cause this issue to arise. Due to this issue not being in line with the documentation of the StatusHub API I would not advise on doing a workaround, as you are bypassing a bug in the application.